# Estimate the minimum of a degree 2007 polynomial on circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a polynomial of degree 2007:

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{2007} a_n z^n$$

If $f$ has exactly 1966 zeros in the unit disc $D$ of course counting multiplicity, prove that:

$$\min_{|z|=1} |f(z)|\leq |a_0|+|a_1|+\cdots +|a_{1966}| $$

I don't have any idea, who can give any suggestions?

Thank all of you!

Comment: @AranKomatsuzaki I believe he's talking about the open disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\min_{|z|=1} |f(z)| > |a_0|+\cdots +|a_{1966}|$. Then, for $z$ such that $|z|=1$,
$$
|f(z)- \sum_{k=1967}^{2007}a_kz^k| = |a_0 + \cdots +a_{1966}z^{1966}| \leq |a_0|+\cdots +|a_{1966}| < |f(z)|
$$
So, by Rouché's theorem, both functions have the same number of zeros in the unit disk. But the polynomial $z^{1967}\sum_{k=0}^{40}a_{k+1967}z^k$ has at least 1967 zeros in there.

Edit: Using Rouché's theorem may be an overkill, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Nice proof, thank you very much!